# Azure Monitor alert for load balancer health probe does not work

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-load-balancer

I have created alert which fires if the average value of health probe status is less than 100. However, this does not seem to alert in cases where the health probe status is `--`, which means that the alert does not work at all. Is there any way I could get alerts whenever the probe status is not 100?

Comment: Can you paste your sample query ? if i comprehend you should be using the count instead of average for your scenario.

Comment: My condition is: Whenever the health probe status is less than 100 count

I did look on the count but that seems to give odd numbers.

Comment: I did test the count as well. It looks to do the same, when probe status is failed the count goes to "--" and does not fire alert.

Comment: Have you configured the backend pool, health probe and rules? is your LB in working state? If yes, then you should be able to see the probe count in the metrics.

Comment: I have and you are correct I can see the probe count in the metrics. The problem is that I cannot get any alert to fire when the probe gets unavailable. My guess is that it is due to the count being "--" instead of well numeric value.